# Building a Postgresql View Over a View

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I've got a problem with one of my clients for OpenERP. I need to build a custom object for them, cause they have a problem where sometimes they get returned products after they have been sold. So I need to mark that as negative and subtract from the total sold from before.

```
SELECT sum(rsm1.product_qty_out) as "out"
     , sum(rsm2.product_qty_in) as "in"
     , rsm2.location_id
     , rsm2.product_id
     , rsm2.month
from report_stock_move as rsm1, report_stock_move as rsm2
where rsm2.location_id in (
    select id
    from stock_location
    where "name" = 'Consumers'
    )
and rsm1.location_id not in (
    select id
    from stock_location
    where "name" = 'Consumers'
    )
and rsm1.location_dest_id = rsm2.location_id
and rsm2.location_dest_id = rsm1.location_id
and rsm1.state = 'done' -- both are in done state
and rsm2.state = rsm1.state
group by rsm2.location_id, rsm2.month, rsm2.product_id
;
```

Anyone have any ideas? Also, I keep getting different results depending upon which table I use for the grouping. Why is that?

**EDIT**
Sorry, in my haste to solve this, I seem to have made my point clear. report_stock_moves that have a location_id of Consumers from a stock_location table need to be negative and summed up into report_stock_moves that have location_id of another place, but Consumer is the location_dest_id.

Example:

```
location_id = Some Place (actually ID of stock_location of course)
product_qty = 8
location_dest_id Consumers
date = 2012-07-02

location_id = Consumer
product_qty = 4
location_dest_id Some Place
date = 2012-07-04
```

Here are two record examples. They have different dates attached to them, so I'd probably want to take the max date, or the date of the returns(from Consumer to Some Place) if I want to union or group them so that when they are put together, i get 4, instead of say 8 if I didn't put them together and only look at what is going into Consumers.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is your View is working is then you can create the OpenERP POstgres Views with working query

Comment: Sorry about that. I was too urgent to reread over what I wrote. Happens to the best of us. Made the edits up about, please take a look again.

Comment: Why cant you use the `return products` wizard in `Warehouse > warehouse management >Delivery orders`

Comment: Did that, doesn't make a difference in this case, cause once it has been moved to consumers, it is a done deal. Totally different move from consumer back to location. You still have to do the math between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone struggles with this for later. I'll paste my answer here. If anyone can help me explain about why union all in here seems to work, I'm all ears. I can do simple SQL, but I don't know much about how unions work, especially in case like this.

```
select max(total.id) as id,
                     sum(total.product_qty) as product_qty,
                     total.location_id as location_id,
                     total.date as "date",
                     total.year as year,
                     total.month as month,
                     total.day as day,
                     total.product_id as product_id
                     from (
                       -- From Consumer back to location
                        select -max(id) as id,
                        -sum(product_qty) as product_qty, 
                        location_dest_id as location_id, 
                        "date", year, month, day, product_id
                        from report_stock_move
                        where location_id in (
                            select id
                            from stock_location
                            where "name" = 'Consumers'
                        )
                        and "state" = 'done'
                        group by location_dest_id, "date", year, month, day, product_id

                        union all

                        -- From Location to Consumer
                        select max(id) as id,
                        sum(product_qty) as product_qty, 
                        location_id, "date", year, month, day, product_id
                        from report_stock_move
                        where location_id not in (
                            select id
                            from stock_location
                            where "name" = 'Consumers'
                        )
                        and "state" = 'done'
                        and location_dest_id in (
                            select id
                            from stock_location
                            where "name" = 'Consumers'
                        )
                        group by location_id, "date", year, month, day, product_id
                     ) as total
                     group by location_id, "date", year, month, day, product_id
```